# How should I retrieve data from firebase and put it into a dictionary?

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, dispatch

I have an organization document with a Members collection inside of it and then a members document inside of that. Inside the members document includes a Map of a user which is a member. The Key is the UserID and 3 values (firstName, lastName, username). I am trying to load in this data into my "Event" class that holds a membersInvited Property that is a dictionary. Inside the Event class is a method to get this data called getOrgMembers(). Even though I have that data in firebase I am getting a nil value for my dictionary. I also am using Dispatch but kind of new to it.

Below is code in the Event Class:

```
var membersInvited: [Member: Bool]?

func getOrgMembers(dispatch: DispatchGroup?) {
    let membRef = BandzDatabase.collection("Organizations").document(currentUser.currentOrgID!).collection("Members").document("members")

    membRef.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print (error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let data = snapshot?.data() {
                for (key,value) in data {
                    if let membArray = value as? [String: Any] {
                        let username = membArray["username"] as? String
                        let firstName = membArray["firstName"] as? String
                        let lastName = membArray["lastName"] as? String
                        let userID = key

                        let member = Member(username: username ?? "", firstName: firstName ?? "", lastName: lastName ?? "", userID: userID)

                        self.membersInvited?.updateValue(true, forKey: member)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dispatch?.leave()
    }
}

struct Member: Hashable {
    var username: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var userID: String

    init (username: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, userID: String) {

        self.username = username
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.userID = userID
    }

}
```

Below is were I call this method from another class:

```
func getMembers() {
    showActivityIndicatory(uiView: self.view)
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    eventMade?.getOrgMembers(dispatch: self.dispatchGroup)
    self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
        stopActivityIndicator()
        print("happens")
        print(self.eventMade?.membersInvited)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. Trace through the code. See where it doesn't do what you expect. You haven't told us anything about what your posted code actually does at runtime so it's hard to help you.

Comment: It returns nil like I said in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I discovered that since I never initilized the dictionary, whenever I was calling to append key-value paires it would not even run since it was an optional. So I changed the decleration to this:

```
var membersInvited: [Member: Bool] = [:]
```